# Slow external monitor (input lag)

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, input

### [solved]

I've read some of the other posts here and other places regarding this, but they did not help me yet. I have *severe* input lag for my external (4k) monitor.

Some facts:

- Running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Using laptop with external screen in "extend" mode
- Using X11, since Wayland isn't compatible with my Nvidia GPU
- I have an AMD CPU
- Input lag can be SEVERAL SECONDS for the external monitor.
- External monitor is connected by HDMI 1.0 cable.

Let's say I open a terminal on laptop monitor, all is fine. Then I move the window to the external screen - laaaagg. Then I move the window back to the laptop screen, and all is fine again.

It was working fine. And then I needed to install some Python packages, and suddenly I can't use an external monitor anymore. I don't remember which packages; some of them were Nvidia CUDA related.

On the external monitor, whenever input lag is observed, I can simply move the mouse to "refresh" the input or something. The point is: If it's slow and I move the mouse, then I get the input shown on screen, and then it's slow again. So I have to constantly move the mouse across the screen.

If I go to Ubuntu Settings -> About, then under "Graphics" it says:
`NVIDIA Corporation / REMBRANDT (rembrandt, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-35-generic)`. So clearly it's not *only* using Nvidia, which might be part of the issue, but again this issue was not present from the start.

- Why is this related to the mouse movement?
- How did this issue just occur after installing some random Python
  packages?
- Can I do something constructive about it, rather than deleting Python completely (if that's even possible) or just buying a new computer? The AMD CPU is constantly a pain to work with, and this is just one of many issues that I've had to deal with.

Comment: It should not be python related I am using a similar setup but I have not found any issues with my external display. Maybe try reinstalling Nvidia Drivers ?

Comment: @UtkarshChandraSrivastava You were right - reinstalling the NVidia driver fixed the issue. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Additional Drivers from the Dash and make a note of the name of the installed Nvidia proprietary graphics driver package. It should be a package of the form `nvidia-driver-xxx` where `xxx` is replaced by a 3-digit version number. Reinstall this package from the terminal with a command of the form:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx && sudo reboot # replace xxx with 3-digit version number
```

Comment: This sounds like the correct answer - even if I reinstalled the driver through the "Additional Drivers" GUI in Ubuntu, I imagine this is equivalent.